# Should we avoid hasNext() call in an Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

Is it advisable not to use iterator.hasNext() in looping over an iterator?

For example I would like to set value obj to each element of a list. I could use the following code or make it more readable by using hasNext() in a loop.

```
int size = list.size();
ListIterator<? super T> itr = list.listIterator();
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
     itr.next();
     itr.set(obj);
}
```

Instead of these lines I could write my code like the following.

```
for (ListIterator<? super T> itr = list.listIterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    itr.next();
    itr.set(obj);
}
```

Comment: Not all iterators have a [known] size; there is no such method to get the size on an `Iterator`.

Comment: @pst He's calling `size ()` on the list, not on the Iterator.

Comment: @SoboLAN Again: there is no such method to get the size on an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it advisable not to use iterator.hasNext() in looping over an iterator?

Um, no. `hasNext` is the *standard* way you iterate with an iterator. That's what the [enhanced-for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) does behind the scenes for an iterable, for example.

Having said that, your code is already ListIterator-specific, as you're using `ListIterator.set` - so your second block of code won't actually compile at the moment. Even if it did, it wouldn't work, as you still need to call `next()`. This would work though:

```
for (ListIterator<? super T> itr = list.listIterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    itr.next();
    itr.set(obj);
}
```

Comment: you are right the second block of code is not accurate. I am going to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when NetBeans refactor you for-each loop to use of iterators, they do it in following way.

for-each:

```
for (T object : list) {
}
```

iterator pattern:

```
for (Iterator<T> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    T object = it.next();
}
```

I think it is totally okay to use hasNext() on iterator while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such recommendation not to use `hasNext`.

The Iterator API list has just three methods, `add`, `remove` and `hasNext`

Also from clean code the second approach looks far better then the first one.

Answer (score 0):

When using an iterator, you should always call the hasNext() method. Otherwise, you may run into a NoSuchElementException when calling the next() method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you should use `hasNext()`, but only for *iterating over*  a collection, not for populating the collection. To fill the collection, work on the collection itself, not on it's iterator and to *read* from the collection use the `for` loop as described by @JMelnik.

**Fill the collection**

```java
Collection<MyObject> list = ...;
while (something) {
    list.add(myObject);
}
```

**Read the collection**

```
for (MyObject myObject : list) {
    ...
}
```